# How to import typescript interface from mobx.d.ts in namespace and use it there?

Tags: typescript2.0, mobx

I need IObservable interface but when I using import here, namespace doesn't work. How can I import this interface right?

// interfaces.d.ts

```js
import { IObservable, IObservableArray } from 'mobx';

namespace TS {

    export interface DefaultObject {
        [key: string]: Object;
    }


    export namespace deviceModel {

        export interface Device<T> {
            isRefreshing :Object,
            topLineProgress :Object,
            appState :Object,
            connection :Object,
            orientation :IObservableArray<T>
        }
    }


    export namespace promoModel {

        export interface promoData {
            status: string
        }
    }
}
```

// someModule.tsx

```js
let props:TS.DefaultObject = { };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEF4O.png)

Comment: I think that looks correct. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Tholle, I'm getting "Cannot find a namespace TS" when I trying:
`let props:TS.DefaultObject = { };`

Comment: that sounds like a different problem. Did you import and export TS correctly (the namespace is not exported in your snippet, from the top of my head it should be)